# How to use thymeleaf inside of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a JSP page with a javascript code that I've written and works well. I need to re-write the same code using thymeleaf, but isn't working. The JSP javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPie);

  function drawChartPie() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Conta', 'Valor'],         
        <c:forEach items="${model.contaCorretora }" var="contaCorretora">
      ['${contaCorretora.tipoConta}', ${contaCorretora.valorAtual}],
    </c:forEach>
      ]);

    var options = {
      title: '${model.pessoa.nome }'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>
```

I didn't find the way to migrate this code to thymeleaf.

**UPDATE 1:**

I've used the code as you suggest me, but still doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[/ 
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPie);

  var array = [[${investimento}]];

  function drawChartPie() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Conta', 'Valor'],         
      for (i in array)
      {
        ['array[i].tipoConta', array[i].valorTotalDolar],    
      }
      ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Teste'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }   

  /]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First enable JavaScript inlining with `th:inline`:

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
```

Then use double-bracket expression to insert an object:

```javascript
var options = {
  title: [[${model.pessoa.nome}]];
};
```

Instead of `foreach`, you should use the fact that Thymeleaf (with help with from Jackson library) can serialize an object to JSON:

```
var contaCorretora = [[${model.contaCorretora}]];
// "contaCorretora" is now a JavaScript object,
// make an array out of it or what you want
```

Comment: and wrap js script in CDATA like this  /*<![CDATA[*/      Your java-script code      /*]]>*/

Comment: Hi, i've written like you suggest me but still doesn't work. What I'm doing incorrect?

Comment: @holmis83 I've chaged the code (I've updated my post with the New code), and the JavaScript is not working in this way...

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida Look at the generated code and debug. The code around that `for` loop does not look syntactically correct ...